# Force Users to change their password on first logon

Tags: 2013, user, password

I'm using SharePoint 2013 Server, and I added a solution ([changepasswordfromsharepoint2013](https://changepasswordfromsharepoint2013.codeplex.com) from codeplex) that permit users to modify their AD password from SharePoint. This is working well.

Now I'm wondering if there is any solution to force users to change their password at next logon. If I check that in active directory user's properties, they won't be able to login in.

Is there a way to force them to land a a specific page for the first time they come ? In my example, the plugin from codeplex bring them on a aspx page that show password modification.
I would like to bring them on this page (and they must not be able to click anywhere else, as they should specify a password now) at they first visit only.

I hope I'm understandable, if not, feel free to ask for more details.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Password Reset from the boostsolution having a feature which i believe solve you issue.

> For security reasons you can force users to change their password on
>   their next logon. This not only enforces security, but also allows
>   users to easily remember passwords they themselves changed.

[SharePoint Password Reset](http://www.boostsolutions.com/password-reset.html)

Comment: thanks for your link. I downloaded it, but I can't understand why there is "free download" and "buy it button" ... I can't find any features comparison. Is that a kind of 30 free trial ? If you ever used these products, do you know ? because almost every product got a "free download" button.

Comment: i am not sure about it. But i think sometime companies give free fro 30 days or limit to the number of users...I think best is contact them.